# Getting full module name in Import hook

Tags: python, import, path, hook

I am implementing an import hook that automatically installs missing modules using pip.

So far it is working OK with simple modules (that have only one level), for instance `unipath`. However if I try to use it with multilevel imports, such as `zope.interface` the importer only gets the first part (`zope`). That causes it to fail as `zope` does not exist in PyPI.

Any idea of how to achieve getting the full module's name when importing it?

Here some code:

```
class PipLoader(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.module = None

    def find_module(self, name, path):
        print "Will install module {}".format(name)
        self.module = None
        sys.meta_path.remove(self)
        try:
            pip_install(name)
            self.module = importlib.import_module(name)
        finally:
            sys.meta_path.append(self)
        return self

    def load_module(self, name):
        if not self.module:
            raise ImportError("Unable to load module")
        module = self.module
        sys.modules[name] = module
        return module

def install():
    sys.meta_path.append(PipLoader())
```

Comment: Ouch, terrible idea. Don't auto-install; what if there are version incompatibilities?

Comment: Don't worry @MartijnPieters ! I assure you that the rest of the application is much more unsafe :P It's just for fun.

Comment: If you replace `__import__` then you get the module globals that of the module imports and much more information.

Comment: Thanks @User ! that did the trick. Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it? If not I will just write one myself.

Comment: I wrote an answer but if you post your code in your answer that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace `__import__` then you get the module globals that of the module imports and much more information.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, the actual code using this technique can be found here: https://github.com/chaosct/pipimport/blob/79120eea4aed66743b5dbab47ba18a2d49c19638/pipimport/__init__.py